# Thunderbird 68.4.1: How to check if a message is marked as "junk"?

Tags: thunderbird-addon

In some self-written add-on for Thunderbird I have to check if some message is marked as "junk".

In Thunderbird **68.3** the following code worked perfectly:

```
isJunk = false;
for(i = 0; i < message.tags.length; i++)
{
    if(message.tags[i] == "junk") isJunk = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, the `tags` array seems always to be empty in Thunderbird **68.4.1** so the code above does not work any longer.

How can I check if some message is marked as "junk" in newer Thunderbird versions?

Comment: Today, I received an answer of a Thunderbird developer: The `tags` array was never intended to contain information about the junk status of the message. Therefore 68.4.1 does not longer provide the information in that array. Unfortunately, future versions will have another property to check for the junk status but in 68.4.1 there is no possibility to do this.

Comment: From [the API documentation](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages.html#messageheader), it looks like the properties you mention (`MessageHeader.junk`, and even `MessageHeader.junkScore`) were added to Thunderbird 74.